# How to disable JMX port for IBM Websphere MQ?

Tags: java, jmx, disable, mqueue

We have tried disabled the jmx for IBM Websphere client using the following and we continue to see that the port is active when our process is running.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=false"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.enabled=false"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dendpoints.default.jmx.enabled=false"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=127.0.0.1"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dspring.jmx.enabled=false"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=false"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=password-file"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=password-file"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dspring.datasource.jmx-enabled=false"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=*"
```